# How to find the complex function corresponding to a potential function?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, harmonic-functions, potential-theory

I have a potential function $F(x,y)$ that satisfies the 2D Laplacian $\nabla^2 F = \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2} =0$. Given the property of potential functions, a linear combination of complex functions in variable $z = x+iy$ and its conjugate $\bar{z} = x-iy$ must always satisfy the 2D Laplacian. Let these functions be $f(z)$ and $g(\bar{z})$.

i.e. we have $\nabla^2 (a f(z) + b g(\bar{z}) =0 $ for any set of complex constants $a$ and $b$. If so, given an $F(x,y)$ is there a way to find the complex functions $f$ and $g$?

For eg: If $F(x,y)=2 \cosh(x)\cos(y)$, I already know that my $f(z) =\cosh(z)$ and $g(\bar{z}) = \cosh(\bar{z})$, and $a=1, b=1$. Several such examples can be constructed by choosing $f$ and $g$. However, is there a way to find $f$ and $g$ from $F$?

Comment: assuming that $F$ is defined on a disc say slightly larger than the unit disc, the holomorphic part is obtained by taking the Cauchy transform of $F$, namely $f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=1}\frac{F(\zeta)d\zeta}{\zeta-z}, |z|<1$ and then the antiholomorphic part $g(\bar z)$ (uniquely defined by $g(0)=0$) is, of course, $F(x,y)-f(z)$ - in general you can adapt this to any disc where $F$ is harmonic and get $f$ which is unique by analytic continuation up to an additive constant this way, with the added bonus that you fix the antiholomoprhic $g$ to be zero at the center of the disc